# How to decide between a French or a German pattern chef's knife?

Tags: knives, knife-skills

I'm getting ready to buy (or commission) a nice 10" chef's knife.  I need to decide between a French or a German pattern.  What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Do you like to "rock" as you cut? Or do you move in more of a straight line? Do you like the way you cut or would you like your blade to help you change your pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is an issue of personal preference.

If you prefer a rocking motion, the German profile suits your style better; if you are a push-and-slide person, the French profile is more suitable for you.  It also possible to find models at various points *within* the range.

See this [Chef Talk](http://www.cheftalk.com/t/62065/french-and-german-chefs-knives-profiles-in-cutting) thread for an in depth discussion (with diagrams at one point). The original poster concludes, quite correctly in my opinion:

> But... let's keep our senses of perspective and humor.  A German knife
>   won't turn a good cutter into a bad one, and a French knife won't do
>   the opposite.  Both profiles suit the classic, European and American
>   styles of food and knife skills.  It comes down to taste and training.